# Merging partial duplicates

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, python

I have a csv file with four columns like this

```
aa,bb,cc,dd  
ee,bb,cc,dd  
ff,bb,cc,dd  
xx,11,22,33  
yy,11,22,33
```

I'd like to turn it into:

```
aa,ee,ff,bb,cc,dd  
xx,yy,11,22,33
```

Basically, find the lines where the last 3 columns are identical and merge the first field.

Does anyone know how to do this in bash or Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Perl

hash `%h` holds the data while the array `@h` manages the order in which the hash elements were encountered. OTW, the hash keys will be selected in a random order.

```
perl -F, -lane '
   BEGIN{ $"=$,=","; }
     push @{$h{"@F[-3..-1]"}}, $F[0];
     $h[-1+keys %h] = "@F[-3..-1]";
   END{ print  @{$h{$_}}, $_ for @h; }
'  yourcsvfile
```

## Sed

```
sed -e '
   :loop
      $!N
      s/^\(.*\)\(\(,[^,]*\)\{3\}\)\n\([^,]*\)\2$/\1,\4\2/
   tloop
   P;D
'  yourcsvfile
```

## Bash

```
sed \$G yourcsvfile | # we add a dummy line to signal last record has been processed
while IFS=, read -r -a A; do
   var=${A[@]: -3:3}
   var=${var// /,}
   case $var in
      "$prev" ) x=${x-}${x:+,}${A[0]} ;;
      * ) case $prev in ?* ) echo "$x,$prev" ;; esac; prev=$var; x=${A[0]} ;;
   esac
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an `awk` program for that:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {OFS = FS = ","}
{
    gsub(/ +$/, "", $4)
    field = $2","$3","$4
    if (field in a)
        a[field] = a[field]","$1
    else
        a[field] = $1
}
END { for (i in a) print a[i], i}
```

And the bonus python program:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

records = OrderedDict()
for line in open('file1'):
    field, key = line.strip().split(',', 1)
    records.setdefault(key, []).append(field)
for key, fields in records.items():
    print(','.join(fields + [key]))
```

result:

```
aa,ee,ff,bb,cc,dd
xx,yy,11,22,33
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It seems to work except that my non-ASCII text shows up weird in the stdout. Also, actually my format is csv... I tried to change the delimiter but the stdout still looks odd.

Comment: Well if we don't know the format, it is a bit tougher to make it work.  Python can make short work of csv, but what some consider csv covers quite a lot of variation.

Comment: Change space to `,`. Are you sure you didn't need `;`?

Comment: I tried to give an upvote but couldn't because I'm still new. When I tried the awk program, I got this:  
xx,yy,11,22,33    
aa,bb,cc,dd  
ee,ff,bb,cc,dd -- so when there are more than two partial duplicates, the merge only applies on two.

Comment: You data has trailing spaces.  I just updated the awk to remove the trailing spaces.  The python already does that.